# REST API Design - Resource relationships and Idempotency of a PUT request: What, exactly, is meant by a full resource representation?

Tags: rest, put, idempotent

I understand that for partial updates, an action must be taken that is not idempotent. To that end, a valid approach is to make a POST request to that resource.

I have a question though about related resources. For example imagine the following resources with their properties:

1. Accounts
   Id
   Name
   Account #
   Users (a collection)
2. Users
   Id
   Name

Now imagine I want to make a partial update to an Account - for example, to change the Account's name.

I could make the following request as a valid partial update:

```
POST /account/id/123

{
    "name" : "My New Name"
}
```

My question is regarding a full PUT request which *must be idempotent and must include a full representation of the resource*.

**Could I do the following as a valid idempotent request?**

```
PUT /account/id/123

{
    "name" : "My New Name",
    "accountNumber" : "654-345-4323"
}
```

Is that considered a valid, idempotent action? I've included all the top level "Account" information, but I question it because I didn't post all the `USERS` that belong to the account as well.

**In order to be a valid idempotent request, would I need to include all of it's sub resources as well in the PUT request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to understand is to consider that the PUT method **ignores** the current state of the target resource, so a "full resource representation" means that it must have all data needed to replace the existent resource with a new one.

In your example, that could be a valid full representation for an account with no users.

It's fine for the server to assume default values when something is missing, but that should be documented properly as some users might confuse with a partial update.

Comment: Ok thanks Pedro. So it's valid, but doesn't do what's intended (leave the relationships intact).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to design the PUT request as the full resource replacement, then this means that you need also to assign values to all the assignable (editable) properties of a resource, including the relations (links) of a resource. Otherwise, the properties which are not set are considered as being set to `null`.

For partial requests, you can use PATCH HTTP method. There is also a convention of PUT if your resource representation is simple enough to allow that, that you can use partial updates.

[PATCH vs. PUT](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html#patch-vs-put)

Quoting:

> ### PATCH vs. PUT
>
> The HTTP RFC specifies that PUT must take a full new resource
>   representation as the request entity. This means that if for example
>   only certain attributes are provided, those should be remove (i.e. set
>   to null).
>
> An additional method called PATCH has been proposed recently. The
>   semantics of this call are like PUT inthat it updates a resource, but
>   unlike PUT, it applies a delta rather than replacing the entire
>   resource. At the time of writing, PATCH was still a proposed standard
>   waiting final approval.
>
> For simple resource representations, the difference is often not
>   important, and many APIs simply implement PUT as a synonym for PATCH.
>   This usually doesn’t give any problems because it is not very common
>   that you need to set an attribute to null, and if you need to, you can
>   always explicitly include it.
>
> However for more complex representations, especially including lists,
>   it becomes very important to be able to express accurately the changes
>   you want to make. Therefore, it is my recommendation now to both
>   provide PATCH and PUT, and make PATCH do an relative update and have
>   PUT replace the entire resource.
>
> It is important to realize that the request entity to PATCH is of a
>   different content-type that the entity that it is modifying. Instead
>   of being a full resource, it is a resource that describes
>   modifications to be made to a resource. For a JSON data model, which
>   is what this essay is advocating, I believe that there are two
>   sensible ways to define the patch format.
>
> 1. An informal approach where you accept a dict with a partial
>      representation of the object. Only attributes that are present are
>      updated. Attributes that are not present are left alone. This approach
>      is simple, but it has the drawback that if the resource has a complex
>      internal structure e.g. containing a big list of dicts, then that
>      entire list of dicts need to be given in the entity. Effectively PATCH
>      becomes similar to PUT again.
> 2. A more formal approach would be to
>      accept a list of modifications. Each modification can be a dict
>      specifying the JSON path of the node to modify, the modification
>      (‘add’, ‘remove’, ‘change’) and the new value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is around "what exactly is meant by a full resource representation".

Comment: If you want to design the PUT request as the full resource replacement, then this means that you need also to assign values to all the assignable (editable) properties of a resource, including the relations (links) of a resource. Otherwise, the properties which are not set are considered as being set to null.

Comment: Ok that was my question. Can you update your answer as such and I will mark as answered.